# IIS Prevent hotlinking of other sites' content on self-hosted websites

Tags: dns, self, hotlinking, hosted

We want to avoid our own users from hotlinking to images and media outside our own domain. Is there a way to do this through IIS (version 8 on Windows Server 2012) ? We have the URL Rewrite module installed, but unsure how to develop a rule that would accomplish what we need.

Pleaes keep in mind I'm wanting to block any hotlinking to *other* websites, and only allow images/media that are located on our own domain. Googling and searching here on stackoverflow results in preventing other sites from hotlinking to one's own self hosted content, not the other way around like we want.

Answer (score 0):

[WMSAuth plugin for Windows Media Services](http://wmsauth.org/) might be something which you might look at. It's not for IIS but you might use the same concept for building your solution.

It's open source so you can [check the sources on github](https://github.com/WMSPanel/wmsauth).

Comment: Thanks. I'll check it out if I don't come across a simpler solution. I'd think I should be able to use the URL Rewrite module in IIS to do an outbound rule possibly, but haven't figured it out yet...